# Trigger an ability an additional time that triggers only once each turn

Tags: magic-the-gathering

With cards like [Sefris of the Hidden Ways](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2B%5BSefris%20of%20the%20Hidden%20Ways%5D%0A) or the new card [Akki Battle Squad](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2B%5BAkki%20Battle%20Squad%5D%0A) they have an additional line stating this ability triggers only once each turn. Will cards like [Teysa Karlov](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2B%5BTeysa%20Karlov%5D) and [Wulfgar of Icewind Dale](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2B%5BWulfgar%20of%20Icewind%20Dale%5D%0A) cause the ability to trigger an additional time even though it can only trigger once each turn? It doesn't say the ability can't trigger more than once each turn?

Comment: Teysa is Historic legal, making this testable on Arena.  I can't at the moment, but anyone want to try it out and report back?

Comment: @ArcanistLupus Three cards currently exist that would make this testable in MTGA historic with Teysa - Dramatic Finale, Ghoulish Procession and Morbid Opportunist, if anyone wanted to build a deck and check, though MTGA hasn't always been the best at properly applying rules edge cases.

Comment: https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/a/57094/5918 :-) (if somebody really wanted to they could test ETB triggers with Yarok as well)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While I don't currently have any official rules on this, this is how I would rule on the situation currently as a Judge:

As a general rule in Magic: the Gathering, "can't" wins over "can", restrictions win over requirements or permission. In this case the "can't" is the triggers once per turn restriction on those cards and the "can" would be triggers an additional time. Because of this rule, the restriction is going to win out and prevent the ability triggering a second time. In the Comprehensive Rules, this "can't wins over must or can" is one of the Golden rules, [rule 101.2](https://mtg.fandom.com/wiki/Magic_golden_rules):

> **101.2** When a rule or effect allows or directs something to happen, and another effect states that it can’t happen, the “can’t” effect takes precedence.

Comment: Not a judge, but as an experienced amateur I also think this is the most sensible interpretation. I'm a little hesitant to upvote anything yet, though, just in case someone shows up with a more clear reference to the rules or something from a high-level judge saying that it actually doesn't work this way.

Comment: @DavidZ I am only L1, so it's fair to take what I say with a grain of salt, but I've added a CR rule reference to my logic if that helps.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/133966/discussion-between-andrew-and-murgatroid99).

Answer (score 6):

I created the following situation in Arena; on my battlefield I had (amongst other things):

- [Teysa Karlov](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Teysa%20Karlov)
- [Dramatic Finale](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Dramatic%20Finale), [Ghoulish Procession](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Ghoulish%20Procession) and [Morbid Opportunist](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Morbid%20Opportunist), three cards with a death trigger and the "only once each turn" wording.
- [Archghoul of Thraben](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Archghoul%20of%20Thraben), [Liliana, Dreadhorde General](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Liliana%2C%20Dreadhorde%20General) and [Midnight Reaper](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Midnight%20Reaper), three cards with a death trigger but without the "only once each turn" wording.
- [Fell Stinger](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Fell%20Stinger) (just as a target creature to die)

I then cast [Infernal Grasp](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Infernal%20Grasp), targeting the Fell Stinger. I got only one copy of the Dramatic Finale, Ghoulish Procession and Morbid Opportunist triggers, but two copies of the Midnight Reaper, Liliana, and Archghoul of Thraben triggers, thus proving Teysa's ability was working.

Therefore at least with Teysa in Arena we can conclude the trigger is not doubled.

Comment: Interesting experiment.  To play devil's advocate for a second, how does this prove that these abilities shouldn't trigger more than once?  I mean, Arena couldn't possibly have bugs in it right? /s

Comment: @Becuzz My final paragraph is very carefully phrased.

Comment: I think empirical evidence based on what works in Arena is not as good of an answer as citing rules or rulings. The programmers could have created a bug accidentally. It's kind of like saying you did something and weren't arrested, so its legal.